# do i need to use cherry-pick or rebase?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have a directory, in that I've two different type of features: *feature 1* and *feature 2*.
and I'm working on ***feature 2*** so I cloned from a commit from where *feature 1* is like 50% completed.

Later, I started working on my feature branch and completed development. In this mean time *feature 1* is also completed. Now I need to get that latest source of *feature 1* to my branch.

So, using which techniques I can achieve this in git command? cherry-pick or rebase or any other commands?

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master` (replace *origin* and *master* with actual names).

Comment: You only need to merge feature1 into feature2 so just `git merge feature1`

Comment: Thanks guys. its working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted latest source  of feature 1 , so I performed following,

```
git checkout feature1
git pull
git checkout feature 2
git merge feature1
```

By doing above git commands i'm able to get latest of ***feature 1***.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a rebase to get the code, on your feature branch do a

```
git pull --rebase origin <branch name>
```

(assuming the remote is with name origin here)